# How do I pull <b> text </b> underneath an href tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to find a way to pull both some links and their associated text with beautiful soup. The HTML is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffff99">
        <font size="2">
            <a href="link/I/Want.htm">
                <b>Text I Want</b>
            </a>
        </font>
     </td>

<tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffff99">
        <font size="2">
            <a href="link/I/Want.htm2">
                <b>Text I Want2</b>
            </a>
        </font>
     </td>
```

I can pull the link no problem:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('link/I/Want'))
```

However I would like to be able to pull the text as well and have it associated with the link. Either by having them back to back in a list, or by having them in separate lists in the same order so I can use a zip() function.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('link/I/Want')):
    links.append({"link" : link["href"],  "text": link.find_all("b")[-1].get_text(strip=True)})
print (links)
```

Outputs:

> [{'link': 'link/I/Want.htm', 'text': 'Text I want'}, {'link': 'link/I/Want2.htm', 'text': 'Text I want2'}]

Comment: Same thing for this, for some reason its returning None as the text

Comment: Post the html snippet where that part occurs.

Comment: Im not understanding what your asking for?

Comment: Please copy the html structure to here so we can help you find out where the code fails.

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with Using findNextSibling(), if I'm not mistaken the <b> tag is a child of the <a> tag?

Comment: I can get the text by doing this

Comment: `for i in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('id=')):`

Comment: `a = i.find('b')`

Comment: okay, so now I need to remove the <b> tags from my text. How would I create a loop to do this for all of them? Currently my output looks like this : `{'Text': [<b>My Text</b>}, {'URL': 'link/I/Want.htm'}`

Comment: I should clarify, the when I used .get_text() it returned that it won't work on a 'None' type object.

Comment: In one of your entries there isn't a b tag to be found, that is why your are getting the None error. You should check for a tag when getting the text.

Answer (score 0):

use dict comprehension to get data out of the soup object.

`get_text()` will concatenate all the decendent text.

```
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('link/I/Want'))
data = {link.get_text(strip=True): link['href'] for link in links}
```

out:

```
{'Text I Want': 'link/I/Want.htm', 'Text I Want2': 'link/I/Want.htm2'}
```

Answer (score -2):

s.html is the html file

We can pull out the text content in all the  tags as follows

```
from BeautifulSoup import *

fh = open('s.html')
html = fh.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')

for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href',None),soup.find('a').findNext('b').contents[0]
```